# Postfix configuration issue with fips on centos 7; mailgun relay

Tags: centos, rhel, postfix, hashsum, sasl

I am trying to setup postfix to relay all mail generated on the local machine via SMTP to a mailgun relay.  I have used the mailgun relay before with success on an ubuntu server, but I am migrating to a Centos 7 server which I will be running in FIPS mode.  There error log is below, slightly sanitized.  I have a small enough network that I choose to have each machine reach out to mailgun individually (this the loopback-only, 127.0.0.0/8 restrictions) and no firewall open port allowing smtp in to the machine.

I assume the FIPS mode (and with it disabling of MD5) is causing problems, but I don't know how to overcome it or if it is even possible for tls_fprint to use some supported hash such as sha256 or sha512.  However, the relay=none is slightly concerning since I have relayhost set, but perhaps that is because the smtp process is failing?

Any help would be appreciated!

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps =
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
relayhost = [smtp.mailgun.org]:587
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender
sender_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_check
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

/var/log/maillog:

```
Apr 28 20:04:15 HOSTNAME postfix/pickup[85556]: SOME_ID_NUMBER: uid=0 from=<root>
Apr 28 20:04:15 HOSTNAME postfix/cleanup[85583]: SOME_ID_NUMBER: message-id=<20180429000415.SOME_ID_NUMBER@FQDN>
Apr 28 20:04:15 HOSTNAME postfix/qmgr[85557]: SOME_ID_NUMBER: from=<root@FQDN>, size=2261, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 28 20:04:16 HOSTNAME postfix/smtp[85585]: fatal: tls_fprint: error computing md5 message digest
Apr 28 20:04:17 HOSTNAME postfix/qmgr[85557]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
Apr 28 20:04:17 HOSTNAME postfix/qmgr[85557]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
Apr 28 20:04:17 HOSTNAME postfix/master[85555]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp pid 85585 exit status 1
Apr 28 20:04:17 HOSTNAME postfix/master[85555]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtp: bad command startup -- throttling
Apr 28 20:04:17 HOSTNAME postfix/error[85587]: SOME_ID_NUMBER: to=<MY@EMAIL.com>, relay=none, delay=1.7, delays=0.05/1.6/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (unknown mail transport error)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many more hours of trying to figure it out, including turning up debug on the smtp and tlsmgr processes in master.cf, I was able to determine that the FIPS disabling md5 was indeed the issue.  Adding the following to master.cf fixed the issue:

```
smtp_tls_fingerprint_digest=sha256
```

Setting to sha1 and sha512 also worked.  Note that the postfix documentation warns about setting to anything other than sha1 or md5 (md5 being the default).  From the documentation:

```
While additional digest algorithms are often available with OpenSSL's libcrypto, only those used by libssl in SSL cipher suites are available to Postfix. For now this means just md5 or sha1.
```

However, for my needs sha256 seems to be working just fine.

Comment: For me it was in main.cf, not master.cf.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wany to configure relay host then you have to change the default entry of /etc/postfix/postfix.conf to the desired relay host.
I hope this link will helpfull for you

https://serverfault.com/questions/878841/cant-relay-on-postfix-accessing-it-from-external-ip